# Crossing the US Canada border on foot (or renting a car)

Tags: usa, canada, borders

To start, we have Canadian citizenship and passports. I have two questions:

1) Is it permissible to cross the Rainbow bridge on foot with luggage? We are currently on vacation in the US and can get a ride up to the border by a family member.

2) Is it possible to rent a car in Buffalo and return the car in Toronto?

Comment: I crossed the Rainbow Bridge on a bicycle a couple of months ago. It was under construction at the time but the pedestrian walkway did appear to be open. AFAIK the construction is supposed to be complete by now.

Comment: Did you consider renting a car in Canadian Niagara Falls?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Bridge_(Niagara_Falls)).
2. It seems so.  I checked the website of one car rental company, which quoted a price of around $180 for a one-day one-way rental between the Buffalo airport and the Toronto airport.  The price for returning the car to the same location was about $50.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to find a way to Fort Erie (immediately across the river from Buffalo) and rent a car there.